# Automotive Power MOSFETs to switch 80A+ - how can it work?

Tags: mosfet

I have been thinking about a method of switching large currents in an Automotive application. I asked another question about tripswitches/circuit breakers but never really found a suitable component to be able to switch 80A @ 12VDC at a low cost, electronically using an MCU.

Now I have received news of International Recifier's new range of Automotive Power MOSFETs - example, [AUIRFB8405](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/1242/0900766b81242e75.pdf) - available here (UK site) http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/mosfet-transistors/7870972/ in TO-220 package (and also SMD and many others) with up to 120A continuous current and 163W max power dissipation. This seems great and could in my mind (for example) take the place of a starter solenoid to drive the 80A or so required for a starter motor... they suggest applications such as electric power steering which would be a similar current I would guess.

But am I right?? I am confused because the battery and starter motor are wired up to MASSIVE conductors, maybe 100mm2 or more (wild estimate) of copper, whereas a TO-220 has a puny bit of tin leg. Can I really solder one inline and pass up to 120A safely (assuming I can dissipate the heat)?

Comment: Current carrying safety limits are defined by the melting point of the insulation, not the area of the conductor.

Comment: "80A or so required for a starter motor" - I think 80A is a rather optimistic estimate, maybe for a small Otto engine. For bigger engines and/or Diesel machines 200A+ seems more adequate. - For your massive current requirements I would definitely look into using multiple FETs in parallel, which a) reduces overall power loss in the switch and b) spreads the power lost (heat) across multiple devices.

Comment: In addition to @HannoBinder's comments, the initial spike of starter current can be huge - no problem for a chunky mechanical solenoid, but perhaps a quick death for a FET. I'm not entirely clear what you gain from directly switching the starter with a FET, it seems one of the last things you'd really bother putting under MCU control rather than a standard key or button.

Comment: Maybe for a [Start-stop System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Start-stop_system)?

Answer (score 4):

The legs of a TO-220 package will melt at a current of 75 Amperes or so, according to [this article](http://www.mcmanis.com/chuck/robotics/projects/esc2/FET-power.html):

> The first surprise was that the TO-220AB package the FETs were installed in had a lower current limit than the FETs! Discussions with the **International Rectifier** FE and later with a rep from **Motorola** confirmed that the limits on the TO-220AB were approximately 75 amps. This limit was due to the **heating of the lead frame to the point where the legs would melt**.

Realistically, the 120 Ampere limit might at best be achieved by applying some sophisticated cooling solution in a lab environment, not in an actual automobile product.

What is relevant though is that spikes of up to 120 Amperes might well be sustainable, if they are short enough.

An alternative approach would be to use multiple of those MOSFETs in parallel in a combination that does not load one single MOSFET with the expected full load current.

Comment: I think the MOSFET die is rated for the 120A current, but the package and bond wires aren't. Some transistors are available in various packages, all with their own limits.

Comment: @jippie As per the datasheet this FET is silicon-limited to 185 Amperes, package-limited to 120 Amperes. I would have to say it is reality-limited to 75 Amperes once one moves beyond the marketing-speak  :-)

Comment: I mixed up the numbers. I fully agree.

Answer (score 0):

Those current ratings are based on the condition that you can get the heat out of the device.  Getting 163 watts out of a TO-220 is not so easy, if you ask me.

Comment: I understand that the heat needs dissipating, but at 2.5mohm Rds (from the specs) and 80A (which is what I need), a rough calculation suggests about 1/10 of that power...which should be achievable. But still that doesn't clear up my confusion over the existing thumb-sized conductors...

Comment: Those cables are so big simply because you can't afford to lose so much power _everywhere_ in your wiring. This is only acceptable in the switches, where there's pretty much no alternative.